# Concatenate List in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have 3 list's which are having one value i want to concatenate the list, so i used **+** operator to concatenate but the output is not what i expected. I need to use the list because in some cases i can get more results instead of one.

Lists:

```
A = ["F"]
B = ["SZLY"]
C = ["RQTS"]
D = ["19230711"]
```

Output:

```
['F']['SZLY']['RQTS']['19230711']
```

Expected Output:

```
FSZLYRQTS19230711
```

**Update:**

I used below code to concatenate. I used **str()** because i want to cast the topmost list element to string.

```
hrk = str(A)+str(B)+str(C)+str(D)
```

How can i get the expected output.

Comment: How exactly did you use `+` here…?

Comment: It also doesn't look like you want to concatenate the lists (= make one list with multiple items), but you want to concatenate all the strings which are in the lists.

Comment: The output you claim is not real output. Please clarify with an actual [mcve].

Comment: It's not at all clear why you thought that would make sense as an approach. The output you get is exactly what you should have expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i am sorry i am being naive, but i am new to python and these things i am just starting to understand. Sorry if i was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` on a `list` prints a representation of the list (for debug purposes). It's bad to process that as string further in your code.

most pythonic way: use `join` in a list comprehension for first & only item of your lists

```
A = ["F"]
B = ["SZLY"]
C = ["RQTS"]
D = ["19230711"]

print(["".join(x[0] for x in (A,B,C,D))])
```

results in:

```
FSZLYRQTS19230711
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
In [32]: A[0]+B[0]+C[0]+D[0]
Out[32]: 'FSZLYRQTS19230711'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
A[0] + B[0] + C[0] + D[0]
```

You are trying to access first element of list so you have to access them by index.

What you are currently doing will create a single list with all the elements. Like:

```
A = ['2414214']
B = ['fefgg']

C = A + B
print C

# Will print
['2414214', 'fefgg']
```